# Motorcycle Track Racing - Late Braking

Tags: road-racing

I've been competing in my local club racing for about a year now, I'm struggling to get to grips (excuse the pun) with late braking.

Currently I'm braking very early, getting all the braking done in a straight line while fully upright and the turning in once I've completed my braking.

I've read up quite a bit on the finer points of trail braking. What are some appropriate techniques and methods to practise it?